# Formula required to return a value if a date is within 1 month of today

Tags: excel

I'm trying to make use of formulae so that if the date in a cell is within 1 month of today, a value is returned.

So if the date is within one month, I would like it to say "RE-TRAINING NEAR". I can't for the life of me make this work. Apologies, i'm sure it's really easy and i'm just being silly!

Thank you!

Comment: `=IF(A1>=edate(today(),-1),"RE-TRAINING NEAR","")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer will depend on what you mean by "within one month". If you just want "within the next 30 days" then you can do:

```
=IF(NOW()>=A1-30,"Training near","No training coming up soon")
```

there A1 is the cell that contains the date of the training.

Comment: Consider [upvoting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) answers that you find helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(A1>=edate(today(),-1),"RE-TRAINING NEAR","")
```

*assumes A1 holds date being considered.

For more on [`edate`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/EDATE-function-3C920EB2-6E66-44E7-A1F5-753AE47EE4F5) and [`today`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TODAY-function-5eb3078d-a82c-4736-8930-2f51a028fdd9)